# Differentiate meta from meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, per-site-meta, community-bulletin

Meta, meta, meta...

On the community bulletin, can we differentiate MSE from the per-site meta? Right now, the two are listed identically in the community bulletin.

Instead of MSE posts saying 'meta', they should say something else to differentiate them. Like blog posts (which say 'blog').

[image]

Comment: I don't like your proposal in the screenshot, the red text is a little bit aggressive. ;-)

Comment: @n.1 I disagree, I think all graphic design needs to look like an afterthought. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After Community Bulletin has been [redesigned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234453/redesigned-community-bulletin), featured posts from MSE have MSE favicon on the left, so they are distinguishable from posts on this site's meta.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I would like to see that, too. It could look like this:

[image]

Moreover, the same thing should IMHO apply for [blog.SE](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/?cb=1). The fact that the text becomes a two-liner is not much a problem since the post title itself is rarely short enough to fit in one line, so no vertical space is added.