# Why are the [featured] on MSE are using one of the 4 slots?

Tags: bug, community-bulletin, featured-tag

According to [the rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/213575):

> Additionally, up to 2 recent (post created in the past two weeks) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts from Meta Stack Exchange will appear in the community bulletins of all sites. These are also labeled "meta". **Note that these will appear in addition to all of the other stuff listed above,** so the list of community bulletin posts might appear longer than usual, depending on the individual site circumstances.

(emphasis on the important part)

According to this, in a very active meta, there should be 4 hot + 1 featured on MSE post, but reality hits hard in the face, as usual:

> [image]

This may be related to [this change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270000/792066). I've seen the same behavior on other SE sites, not only SO.

Comment: ... because otherwise the CB would start to get uncomfortably long?

Comment: @Undo "bulletin posts might appear longer than usual", is the expected behavior.

Comment: There is a possibility that rules (mentioned in your post) are old. [CB was redesigned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234453/redesigned-community-bulletin) later and all the screenshot on that post contain only 4 CB entries (maybe its just by chance).

Comment: @AzizShaikh nope, [Laura edited them when stuff changed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/130893/revisions)

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, Laura's edits were made on May 8 but CB redesign was done on June 23 (after Laura's edits).

Comment: @AzizShaikh well, [Laura was part of the design team](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234453/213575) so, maybe she was just ahead of schedule?

Comment: You are right, it may very well be possible. However [her comment here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234453/redesigned-community-bulletin#comment770922_234453) gives a different picture. Anyways, will look forward to an update from the SE team.